# iOS custom orientation configuration

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm looking for a way to specify two different orientations for my iOS app in Cordova. One set of orientations is for iPad and the other for iPhone. They should be as follows: iPhone - only portrait (regular and upside down), iPad - all 4 orientations.

Up to now, I have used the `config.xml`

```
<preference name="orientation" value="all" />
```

which generates in the `[APP_NAME]-Info.plist` file the following:

```
<key>UIInterfaceOrientation</key>
<array>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string> <!-- remove this -->
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string> <!-- and remove this -->
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```

I then just remove the lines as commented above to give me what I want on build time. Of course, I would prefer a solution that didn't require attention before releasing.

So far I have tried digging through the Cordova docs, but the only mention of something like this is in the `config-file` section of the `plugin.xml` entry, but since this isn't a plugin-specific configuration, I can't see how that would be correct (i.e. which `plugin.xml` would this belong to?)

If possible, I would prefer just to do this with configuration.

### Edit

From @jcaron's comment I tried to add `config-file` elements directly into `config.xml` as follows:

```
<platform name="ios">
  <config-file target="*-Info.plist" parent="UISupportedInterfaceOrientations">
    <array>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    </array>
  </config-file>
</platform>
```

as well as

```
<config-file target="*-Info.plist" parent="UISupportedInterfaceOrientations">
  <array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
  </array>
</config-file>
```

Neither of these worked. I also tried to vary the path, by prepending `APP_NAME/`, `ios/APP_NAME` and `platforms/ios/APP_NAME` in both the above case, but without success.

Comment: You can add config-file elements to config.xml.

Comment: @jcaron I have just tried this and it didn't appear to work. I tried both inside the `<platform name="ios">...</platform>` tag and outside, but to no avail. any advice?

Comment: Please edit your post to add the relevant lines of your config.

Comment: @jcaron edited, as requested

Comment: You can use `target="*-Info.plst"`. The `parents` should probably be `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations` and `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad`, though.

Comment: @jcaron I have updated my edit to reflect this. I tried as you suggested with `*-Info.plist` and the correctly named parent, but it didn't help sadly.

Comment: Can you try adding `mode="overwrite"` next to the parent one?

Comment: @jcesarmobile thanks for the suggestion! it didn't work either unfortunately.

Comment: I think config-file code is one of the first things to run, so it's probably overwritten by the orientation preference. You will need a cordova hook that writes those values, probably for `before_build` event

Comment: Did you keep the `<preference name="orientation" value="all" />`? What is the result in your Info.plist? Do you have too little or too many entries?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [cordova-custom-config](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config) plugin to apply the changes on the `after_prepare` hook, which ensures they are not overwritten by the Cordova defaults (as [@jcesarmobile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1351469/jcesarmobile) points out in the comment above).

Add the plugin to your project:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-custom-config
```

Define the custom config file blocks in your `config.xml`:

```
<platform name="ios">
    <custom-config-file platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist" parent="UISupportedInterfaceOrientations" mode="replace">
       <array>
           <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
           <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
       </array>
    </custom-config-file>
    <custom-config-file platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist" parent="UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad" mode="replace">
       <array>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
       </array>
    </custom-config-file>
</platform>
```